# GWT upload error FileNotFoundException

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I'm uploading the files on the server like this: I create folder on the server and then I put all my uploading files in this folder

```
@Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
            List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
        String response = "";
        int cont = 0;
        userNumber = request.getParameter("userNumber");
        File f = new File(ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath() + "/edoc/"
                + userNumber);
        for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
            if (false == item.isFormField()) {
                cont++;
                try {
                    String extension = item.getName().substring(
                            item.getName().length() - 3);
                    File file = null;
                    file = new File(ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath()
                            + "/edoc/"
                            + userNumber
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                            + item.getName().substring(0,
                                    item.getName().length() - 4) + "."
                            + extension);
                    item.write(file);

                    receivedFiles.put(item.getFieldName(), file);
                    receivedContentTypes.put(item.getFieldName(),
                            item.getContentType());

                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-field>"
                            + item.getFieldName() + "</file-" + cont
                            + "-field>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-name>" + item.getName()
                            + "</file-" + cont + "-name>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-size>" + item.getSize()
                            + "</file-" + cont + "-size>\n";
                    response += "<file-" + cont + "-type>"
                            + item.getContentType() + "</file-" + cont
                            + "type>\n";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new UploadActionException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        removeSessionFileItems(request);
        return "<response>\n" + response + "</response>\n";
    }
```

It works ver well on my colleague computer, but on my computer I get an error
[image]

There is an error in file name. Help me please fix my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the file name is not displaying correcly. So the problem is the encoding of the Request/Response. You need to add a filter servlet. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2009/05/character-encoding-filter-java-servlets.html#.VNIo2vldXiI).